# add permissions to Azure RM AD application via powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I can create a new Azure RM AD application like so:

```
New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "xxx" -HomePage "xxx" -IdentifierUris "xxx" -ReplyUrl "xxx"
```

I am trying to add application permission to this, so that the app will be created with my specified permissions. The permission I want looks like this in the manifest:

```
"requiredResourceAccess": [
{
  "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "resourceAccess": [
    {
      "id": "311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6",
      "type": "Scope"
    }
  ]
}
]
```

This is a permission for *Windows Azure Active Directory - Delegated - Sign in and read user profile*. 
Is there some way I can add this during of after creating my AD app via powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the command below, change the `ObjectId` , it works fine on my side.

```
$req = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$req.ResourceAccess = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6","Scope"
$req.ResourceAppId = "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId <ObjectId> -RequiredResourceAccess $req
```

The screenshot of **Manifest** :

[image]

Comment: This is an exact copy of what I had already tried, and gave me the error `"A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'requiredResourceAccess'."`. Ah I see you are not using AzureRmAdApplication. Not sure I can use AzureAdApplication. Gonna try

Comment: It works like this. Is there any way to do it with Connect-AzureRmAccount?

Comment: @Green_qaue Unfortunately, we only can do it with Azure AD powershell module , there is no command to set `requiredResourceAccess` in Azure RM powershell module , you could refer to the [command list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/?view=azurermps-6.1.0#active_directory).

Comment: While you did solve my issue. I know it is best practice to use AzureRm, surely there must be some way to set permissions there?

Comment: @Green_qaue Based on the official documentation I mentioned, I am sure that there is no command to set permissions there.

Comment: It's really sad to learn that AzureRM has no way to set AAD permission. I'll try more on it anyway. And I gave both of you an "up".

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an AAD app with given permission. Then you need `New-AzureADApplication` from `AzureAD` module. The code snippet is like:

```
$SiteUri = "https://example.com/"
$displayName = $SiteUri.Host
[string[]]$replyUrl = $SiteUri.AbsoluteUri + ".auth/login/aad/callback"

$reqAAD = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"

# This is "Windows Azure Active Directory".
$reqAAD.ResourceAppId = "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"

# This is to "Sign you in and read your profile"
$permission = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6","Scope"

$reqAAD.ResourceAccess = $permission

New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $displayName -IdentifierUris $SiteUri -Homepage $SiteUri -ReplyUrls $replyUrl -RequiredResourceAccess $reqAAD
```

For more details, you can read https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuregov/2017/12/06/web-app-easy-auth-configuration-using-powershell/